# Injecting property values via Spring by Environment

Tags: java, spring, file, properties

I have a Property File like this:

```
frame.server.dev=mark.is.cool
frame.server.test=chris.is.cool
frame.server.qa=mitch.is.cool
frame.server.prod=cory.is.cool
```

I need to inject the correct value based on the environment.  Since we have one ear file that we move from environment to environment, I need to do something like this:

```
<util:properties id="props" location="classpath:ILog-application.properties"/>
```

and then:

```
@Value ("props.frame.server.#{systemProperties.the.environment}")
private String server;
```

However, I cannot get systemProperties to work, nor can I get it to inject anything after a constant.  Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
@Value ("#{props['frame.server.' + systemProperties['the.environment']]}")
```

Comment: Perfect.  Just what I needed.  As you can tell, I am quite a noobie at annotations and properties.  I have not found a good tutorial on this that did not assume lots of Spring knowledge..  Thanks!

Comment: @silver: Expression in `#{...}` is a Spring Expression Language, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html.